# I get error while print anything in terminal in xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

(lldb) po print("Hello World")

error: expression failed to parse:
error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please enable the expression log by running "log enable lldb expr",then run the failing expression again, and file a bugreport with the log output.

---

Help me solve this error - Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do any research yourself? Here are some similar questions to go through, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977271/lldb-couldnt-irgen-expression, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776459/whats-the-solution-for-error-couldnt-irgen-expression-no-additional-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616652/lldb-po-complain-error-expression-failed-to-parse-error-couldnt-realize-type or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716637/xcode-10-lldb-couldnt-irgen-expression

Comment: I did research a lot but i could not find proper solution about this.